# "Error: Unexpected. Please try again." on JOIN

Tags: google-bigquery

Query Failed
Error: Unexpected. Please try again.

I'm getting this ambiguous error on a JOIN with 2 keys. Searching only gives me a "it's a bug, we're working on it" from a few months ago.

```
SELECT a.user_key as user_key, b.bundleid as bundleid, a.dateFirst as dateFirst
FROM (
  SELECT user_key, dateFirst
  FROM game.firstTable) as a
JOIN EACH (
  SELECT user_key, bundleid, timestamp
  FROM game.prodbundle) as b
ON a.user_key = b.user_key AND a.dateFirst = b.timestamp;
```

Any new bugs or known issues?

Comment: I get the same error while executing pretty much the same query except that there is no use of timestamp.
The query return : "Error: Unexpected. Please try again." instead of result.
The query works fine without any changes on it since more than 2 months ago, executed every morning until today..

Comment: Working now? Look at Jordan's answer

Answer (score 4):

We upgraded to a new version of the query engine yesterday, and there was an inconsistency in error reporting that caused "Error: Unexpected" errors in some cases when using JOIN ON and GROUP EACH. That change was rolled back as of this morning at around 10 am PST.

We're still investigating whether it is just mis-categorization of a resources exceeded error that should have been returned or whether there is another problem.

Please let us know if you continue to see this problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug on joining timestamps, but also a temporary fix you can implement. You can bypass it by transforming them to microsends with `TIMESTAMP_TO_USEC(dateFirst)` in the SELECT statements.

Look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/17055115/132438.

Comment: That didn't seem to work right away. I broke it down to the individual SELECT statements to make 2 temp tables (with 'TIMESTAMP_TO_USEC') and it still gave me an error with no JOIN, but only if I had a Destination table selected. If I had it write it out, it worked fine. 
Then did Save to Table and it worked fine. Now my JOIN does work on the USEC times though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There were a but and it was fixed after the change you have made, the query now returns proper results as expected. Thanks.